# Are there any accident reports that mention hacked/compromised avionics as a factor?

Tags: airline-operations, aircraft-systems, avionics, security

Does anyone know of any documented examples of airline accidents caused by hacked or otherwise deliberately compromised avionics?

Comment: It may be more instructive to also ask "What preventative measures are in place to mitigate hacked or compromised avionics" since many of the answers include "There are no obvious incidents, and I wouldn't expect any because XYZ."

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Searching the [NTSB Accident Database](http://www.ntsb.gov/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/index.aspx) which also covers some international commercial flights for the key words "hack", "hacked" do not provide any results related to hacked avionics. Likewise using the keyword "tampered" does not provide any results related to deliberate tampering with avionics (mostly "tampered" wreckage).

There is one individual, [Chris Roberts](https://www.wired.com/2015/05/feds-say-banned-researcher-commandeered-plane/), who claims to have hacked into the In-Flight Entertainment System (IFE) to cause the aircraft to deviate from its course, however I find it highly suspicious. From a security perspective, I can't of any good reason to have the [IFE network on the same network as any avionics](https://www.wired.com/2015/05/possible-passengers-hack-commercial-aircraft/), however that isn't to say that there isn't some possible connection. The FBI certainly [didn't think it was very funny](http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Chris-Roberts-Application-for-Search-Warrant.pdf).

So as of today there have not been any aviation accidents that are attributed to hacked or deliberately tampered-with avionics as a cause of said accident. The closest thing I think you will find is pilots loading incorrect flight plans, outdated (or even pre-dated) navigation data, and other cases of pilots not correctly using the equipment.

---

I did read your original question and would like to clarify. Conspiracy theories, guesses, and internet speculation are not a replacement for hard evidence. In the case of MH-17 the wreckage was recovered and no evidence has been presented in the favor of hacking, while there is a lot of evidence of the shoot-down. Airliners even at cruising altitude can be shot down by surface to air missiles rather easily.

As for MH-370, until the wreckage is found we may never know (and even if it is we may never know). Black boxes do not have an indefinite life span especially if they are under water. Until then theories of that flight being hacked are just as credible as those saying aliens abducted the entire flight and they are living on Neptune in specially constructed Igloos.

Comment: "I can't think of any good reason to have the IFE network on the same network as any avionics."  Unfortunately, there are bad reasons to have the IFE network on the same network as avionics (not that I know that's been done, I'm just saying.  For example, I can't think of any good reason why a car's entertainment system is on the same network as the engine controller/braking system, but we know that's done.)

Comment: The IFE needs to at least read the flight data, since it is displaying them. So it is up to the bridge to isolate it the other way and there can be a bug in it. @davidbak, in car, the “entertainment” system is also configuration system for many things, which is why it needs connection to the main bus and it must be two-way in that case. In the IFE case the data flow can at least be restricted to one-way.

Comment: I think the FBI reaction was stupid. They should have got the plane in question for a couple of hours and ask him to demonstrate it during ground run. If it succeeded, then he just raised valid concern, so should be thanked and FAA should enforce fixing it. Only if he failed, then it would be correct to charge him — with spreading panic.

Comment: @JanHudec - In the car case, the ent/nav system doesn't have to be on the bus, where it can read/write to any device.  There could be a point-to-point connection to a specialized controller that isolates (filters) the ent/nav system from the vehicle control systems.  And the same for the IFE system too: There could be an output-only stream (separate from any bus/network, and output-only based on the electronics it is built of) from the flight network to the IFE network (for all I know, that's the way its done).

Comment: @davidbak, well, the one car ent/nav system I have a bit of experience with was composed of two units, one running the user interface and nav and the other running the back-end (which included radio there). IIRC only the back-end was connected to CAN, the two boards had ethernet between them. So it was _somewhat_ as you say. Still, CAN is a two-way bus, so if the back-end board is compromised, controllers can be accessed. However ARINC 429 is one-way (one-to-many), which should make it harder to break.

Comment: The problem is not to have things connected or not (they are), but how security is enforced using credentials. In the new era of virtualization virtual LANs are physically connected, but [logically segmented](https://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/products/nsx/vmw-nsx-network-virtualization-design-guide.pdf). Did you know that your Intel CPU can [access a network and exchange data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Active_Management_Technology) when the laptop is powered off?

Comment: @mins True, however consider the implications of connecting cabin accessible equipment to the avionics vs adding a GPS for the flight path following, I still can't imagine a good reason for them to be physically connected, even if segregated.

Comment: @JanHudec I don't feel the same way about the FBI reaction. If he can't reproduce, its a threat (try running through the airport yelling "bomb" once, even if you don't have one). If he can, then he's compromising the safety of others (what if he locked the pilots out somehow and they crashed?). Just because you can do something but never intended to do damage doesn't mean it isn't illegal. If he wanted to demonstrate this, he should have brought it to the FBI's attention **before attempting to do it on an active flight, or 15 as he said**.

Comment: As @JanHudec mentioned, when using industrial serial buses (CAN, SDI, ...) manufacturers are not really worried about connecting everything to the same wire, and often modern security concepts have yet to spread within the engineering dept. I do believe avionics manufacturers are more concerned, but not sure how much more. The FA call button is connected to the FA system, connected to the audio panel, connected to the VOR, connected to the GPS, connected to the ACARS, etc.

Comment: "I can't think of any good reasons to connect it to the passenger network" isn't the same as "There are no good reasons", which itself isn't the same as "It's not connected to the passenger network".  I think you're writing from a position of ignorance here.  For example, despite @davidbak's comment, there *are* good reasons why the entertainment system in cars *is* connected to the engine controller system: when you drive faster, your car stereo's volume automatically increases.  You might not consider that good judgement, but that connection *does* exist, in cars.

Comment: Similarly, for airplanes, my understanding is that in some modern airplanes, the two networks *are* connected. The connections are supposed to have firewalls and logical segmentation that are hopefully adequate to prevent risks, but it's hard to say for sure that this is the case, based solely on public information -- there just doesn't seem to be enough information publicly available to say for sure.  I'm not an expert on this and I can't make authoritative statements about it... but it seems you might not be either. I'd suggest removing that part of the commentary in your answer.

Comment: @D.W. Actually, if that (audio volume increase) was a reason used to justify putting the entertainment system on the _same bus_ as the engine controller I would call that a _bad_ reason.  (I was not objecting to _connections_, just being on the same _network_ (or _bus_). You could reach a safer design by having the engine controller broadcast, via some transmit-only mechanism, the desired telemetrics.)

Comment: @davidbak, that's fine.  As I already wrote, you might not consider it good judgement... but as I said, they *are* connected.  The fact that you think there's no good reason to connect them does *not* imply they are in fact disconnected.

Comment: @D.W. I said I can't think of a good reason for it to be, not that it isn't connected. I wasn't trying to imply that the systems are not connected, only that it isn't a good idea to have a system, especially with accessible ports in the passenger cabin, connected to critical flight controls.

Comment: I know.  What I said is, I suspect you're writing from a position of ignorance.  (I hope you won't take this personally.)  I think the fact that you can't think of a good reason isn't really relevant here to the question that actually matters: which is, are they in fact connected?  A statement that you can't think of a good reason for them to be connected unavoidably risks lending the impression that you intend for readers to infer that they probably aren't connected.  I think your answer would be improved by removing that statement.  Anyway, I've made my case; from here it's up to you.

Comment: @D.W. Part of my job is ensuring the security of control systems, systems that would have major consequences if compromised. I've written papers on industrial security and securing control systems from penetration and internal attacks, so I'm not exactly writing from a position of ignorance. Designing interconnected control systems is what I've been doing for a living for the past 15+ years.

Comment: Not ignorance about computer security in general or in industrial systems specifically... but rather, ignorance about the very specific question of whether the avionics networks are or aren't connected to passenger entertainment networks in any passenger airplane in current service.  See also my comments on the other answer for some links that might indicate why I'm raising this point.  (I'll also say that I've upvoted your answer and I find it helpful.  I am just suggesting one minor point on which I think it could be improved.)

Comment: An example a what is usual in industry: "*In an aircraft network, there will be lots of systems connected in network. They will be synchronizing their time  with GPS. It  will be costly to  implement GPS receivers in each systems in the network. So, in an aircraft mainly central system will be getting its time from GPS. Other systems connected to central system will have to synchronize their time with the central system.*" ([source](https://www.irjet.net/archives/V2/i3/Irjet-v2i373.pdf)). First "good" reason: **cost**! I'm not saying this will be done, just wanted to illustrate the mindset.

Comment: Related: [Networked Local Area Networks in Aircraft: Safety, Security, and Certification Issues, and Initial Acceptance Criteria](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/design_approvals/air_software/media/AR-08-31.pdf) /// and /// [Fly-By-Wireless for Next Generation Aircraft: Challenges and Potential solutions](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.257.8406&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Answer (score 3):

No.  Near as I know, current navigation and flight control avionics are separate from internet connected components, so 'hacking' them is physically impossible.

Now, more types of cockpit avionics are becoming Bluetooth compatible, allowing for interconnectivity with internet connected mobile devices or apps eg Garmin Pilot, ForeFlight, etc., allowing a person to download a flight plan into a GNSS head for example.  Maybe some hacker at some point will analyze a security flaw within these avionics and be able to exploit this.

In addition, these systems often take software updates in the form of SD cards, USB thumb drives, etc. so there is a possibility of introducing malware into the system that way as well.

But even if a GPS head were attacked that way, there would be no means for it to gain access to the control systems of the a/c, the system could be manually shut down, and backup means of navigation used.

But in the era of Stuxnet and budding developments of cyber weaponry paralleling the development of the Internet of things, anything may be possible in the future; just not now.

Comment: *"Near as I know, current navigation and flight control avionics are separate from internet connected components, so 'hacking' them is physically impossible."* Hacking doesn't require the internet, just physical access. Also, Stuxnet is specific to Siemens PLC control systems (I'm a controls engineer) which really doesn't have a parallel in avionics...

Comment: *"Near as I know, current navigation and flight control avionics are separate from internet connected components"* - This does not appear to be accurate.  See, e.g., https://www.wired.com/2015/04/hackers-commandeer-new-planes-passenger-wi-fi/, which states that in some modern jets, the flight control avionics are on the same network as passenger entertainment systems.  There are supposedly firewalls, and if those firewalls are free of bugs this might be adequate to prevent the risks... but that's different from saying they are separate networks, or that hacking is "physically impossible".

Comment: See also https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/01/hacking_the_boe.html and http://www.dailytech.com/Boeing+787+Network+Vulnerability+Reports+Misleading/article10251.htm.  My guess/speculation is that many of the press articles are probably massively over-hyping the risk... but at the same time, the risk can't be completely discounted, and that statements that hacking is "physically impossible" are irresponsible and can't be justified based on the publicly available evidence.

Comment: That Wired article and the Schneider blog are tantamount to carnival barking.  Having worked on these kinds of aircraft, cockpit systems, flight controls, and IFEs, I can tell you there is no hard connection between critical avionics such as the flight control computers, air data computers, radios, nav heads, AFCS, auto throttles, etc., and satellite based WiFi networks.  No, as of today it is virtually impossible for a person working remotely to commandeer an aircraft by hacking into a IFE network.